# Evaluating performance in Bluemix spark

Tags: performance, apache-spark, ibm-cloud, pyspark

I run query and want to evaluate performance (the execution ime)
what i tried :

```
t0 = time.time()
df =sqlContext.sql(query)
df.count()
t1 = time.time()
```

can I be sure that the query completed and t1-t0 is the query run time?

Comment: Given this particular piece of code? No. Some data could be fetched from cache, it doesn't explain dependencies (which could be cached, loaded form scratch) and includes communication with the client. Spark UI is probably a better place to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On IBM Analytics for Apache Spark, in your notebooks go to the "Palette" and choose "Environment". There you can see a link to the Spark History Server where you can investigate your spark jobs.

For each Spark job the computation time is listed.